# Error "Exception class raised Bus Error (10)" al ordenar tabla de memoria por campo tipo Float

Tags: android, delphi

Tengo un detalle en Android con el componente KbmMemtable en Delphi 10.4: Cuando ordeno una tabla de memoria por un campo de tipo Float, la aplicación cierra o muestra un mensaje de error, esto no ocurre cuando ejecuto la aplicación en windows. Cuando yo hago el debug a la aplicación, me aparecen dos mensajes, el primero dice: "Exception class raised Bus Error (10)" y el segundo: "class of exception raised EAccessViolation with message ''.".

```
procedure TMainForm.BtnAddRecordsClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    AddRecord('A1', 'Test 1', 1500, 1);
    AddRecord('A2', 'Test 2', 3500, 2);
    AddRecord('A3', 'Test 3', 4500, 3);
    AddRecord('A4', 'Test 4', 500, 4);
    AddRecord('A5', 'Test5', 10500, 5);
end;
procedure TMainForm.BtnSortClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    MemTable.SortFields := 'Field3_Float';
    MemTable.Sort([mtcoDescending]); //Aquí ocurre el error 
end;

procedure TMainForm.AddRecord(Field1,Field2: String; Field3: Double; Field4:Integer );
begin
    MemTable.Append;
    MemTable.FieldByName('Field1_Str').asString:=Field1;
    MemTable.FieldByName('Field2_Str').asString:=Field2;
    MemTable.FieldByName('Field3_Float').asFloat:=Field3;
    MemTable.FieldByName('Field4_Int').asInteger:=Field4;
    MemTable.Post;
end;
```

Cree un proyecto nuevo utilizado la tabla de memoria "MemTable" de kbmMemtable al cual le agrego registros al precionar un botón que ejecuta el evento: BtnAddRecordsClick, una vez termia tengo otro botón para ordenar con el evento BtnAddRecordsClick y luego al ejecutarse ese evento presento el siguiente mensaje de error: " Access violation at address C0DA25C2, accessing address BE3972CB. ", aveces no muestra el mensaje de error si no que se cierra la aplicación.

Version: Embarcadero® Delphi 10.4 Version 27.0.37889.9797
Version: kbmmemtable: 7.85.00 Standard Edition

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español, [edit] tu pregunta y traduce a español que es el idioma de este sitio

Comment: ¿Parece un bug en el componente, lo has consultado/reportado al fabricante?